# GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

Tags: c, opencv, gtk, iup

I am attempting to run a basic application using [Iup](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/) and [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). The main goal of the app is to display an image and allow the user to analyze in various interesting ways, but that is irrelevant right now.  What I need to know is what the following error messages mean, and how they might be fixed.  My application is still able to run just fine, and displays the image for analysis, but these errors seem to get reprinted every time i repaint the window:

```
(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! gdk-pixbuf loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure.

** (frame:1840): WARNING **: Pixbuf theme: Cannot load pixmap file /usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Scrollbars/scrollbar-v-trough.png: Failed to load image '/usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Scrollbars/scrollbar-v-trough.png': reason not known, probably a corrupt image file


(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

** (frame:1840): WARNING **: Invalid borders specified for theme pixmap:
        /usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Scrollbars/scrollbar-v-trough.png,
borders don't fit within the image

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! gdk-pixbuf loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure.

** (frame:1840): WARNING **: Pixbuf theme: Cannot load pixmap file /usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Scrollbars/slider-v-normal.png: Failed to load image '/usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Scrollbars/slider-v-normal.png': reason not known, probably a corrupt image file


(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

** (frame:1840): WARNING **: Invalid borders specified for theme pixmap:
        /usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Scrollbars/slider-v-normal.png,
borders don't fit within the image

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! gdk-pixbuf loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure.

** (frame:1840): WARNING **: Pixbuf theme: Cannot load pixmap file /usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Scrollbars/stepper-up-insensitive.png: Failed to load image '/usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Scrollbars/stepper-up-insensitive.png': reason not known, probably a corrupt image file


(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

** (frame:1840): WARNING **: Invalid borders specified for theme pixmap:
        /usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Scrollbars/stepper-up-insensitive.png,
borders don't fit within the image

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! gdk-pixbuf loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure.

** (frame:1840): WARNING **: Pixbuf theme: Cannot load pixmap file /usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Scrollbars/stepper-down-insensitive.png: Failed to load image '/usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Scrollbars/stepper-down-insensitive.png': reason not known, probably a corrupt image file


(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

** (frame:1840): WARNING **: Invalid borders specified for theme pixmap:
        /usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/Scrollbars/stepper-down-insensitive.png,
borders don't fit within the image

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(frame:1840): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion `GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the GTK+ theme you are using (Mint-X).  Either the image is broken or it does not respect what it is expected for the scrollbar.  Nothing related with your code.

If you try a different theme (assuming the new one is not broken), you should not see that error.  Also, you should report the bug to Linux Mint.  You can also check whether you have the latest version available (see http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mint-x-theme/).

Also, if you are brave enough, you can try to fix it by yourself using the git repository: https://github.com/linuxmint/mint-x-theme

Answer (score 2):

This error appears if you have compiled `gdk-pixbuf` with dynamic modules at runtime, but it can't find a required loader where it expects to find it. It can happen if you statically linked gdk-pixbuf into your application but didn't ship the loader files.

Best solution is to recompile gdk-pixbuf with all loaders embedded into the library:

```
./configure --disable-modules --with-included-loaders=yes
```